# Best way to retrieve a value from a string java

Tags: java, string

If I am being passed a string that contains comma delimited key-value pairs like this

`seller=1000,country="canada",address="123 1st st"`, etc.

There seems like there must be a better way than parsing then iterating through.

What is the best way to retreive a value from this string based on the key name in Java?

Comment: No, there really isn't any way around parsing. Are you asking for an optimized parsing algorithm? What's your beef with just parsing the whole `String` into a `Map`?

Comment: No beef with parsing the String into a Map however there is only one key-value pair I am interested in and it only appears in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own CSV parser, it's not very complicated but there are a few corner cases to be carfull with assuming of course you are using standard CSV format.

But why reinventing the wheel...

You can try looking up a CSV parser like

- [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)
- [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/)
- [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/)

There are others, look around I'm sure you will find one that suits your needs.

Comment: I have used OpenCSV for exactly this kind of thing, and it works great.

Comment: I remember a few years back I was looking for such library and could not find one so I made my own parser.  I did get it to work no problem but ended up spending a wee bit too much time nailing down all the corner cases.  That said, the data I was receiving did not really follow standard CSV so even if I did choose a parser I probably would have had to tweek it a bit !  Still... i'm all for not reinventing the wheel if I can help it

Comment: I want to downvote for suggesting rolling yet another CSV parser, and upvote for recommending a few existing ones. Stack Overflow needs a leftvote button.

Comment: There are times where the existing libraries just wont cut it, most likely because someone else decided they would roll their own library instead of using existing ones.  Still, I rephrased the answer to put emphasis on not reinventing as I do, in fact, agree with you on that  :-)

Answer (score 7):

Since release 10 [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides a class [MapSplitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html) which does exactly that kind of things:

```
Map<String, String> params = Splitter
    .on(",")
    .withKeyValueSeparator("=")
    .split("k1=v1,k2=v2");
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should use a CSV parsing library to parse the comma separated values. **Correctly** parsing CSV data isn't as trivial as it first seems. There are lots of [good arguments](http://jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/java-csv-file-parsing) to not reinvent that wheel.

This will also future proof your code and be code you don't have to test or maintain.

I know the temptation to do something like `data.split(',');` is strong, but it is fragile and brittle solution. For just one example, what if any of the values contain the ','.

Second thing you should do is then parse the pairs. Again the temptation to use `String.split("=");` will be strong, but it can be brittle and fragile if the right hand side of the `=` has an `=` in it.

I am not a blind proponent of regular expressions, but used with restraint they can be just the right tool for the job. Here is the regular expression to parse the name value pairs.

The regular expression [^(.*)\s?=\s?("?([^"]*)"?|"(.*)")$](http://www.rubular.com/r/UFOJBOEj9x), click the regular expression to test it online interactively. This works even for multiple double quotes in the right hand side of the name value pair.

This will match only what is on the left side of the first `=` and everything else on the right hand side, and strip the optional `"` off the string values, while still matching the non-quoted number values.

Given a `List<String> list` of the encoded name value pairs.

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*)\s?=\s?("?([^"]*)"?|"(.*)")$");
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(list.size());
for (final String nvp : list)
{
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(nvp);
    m.matches();
    final String name = m.group(1);
    final String value = m.group(2);
    System.out.format("name = %s | value = %s\n", name, value);       
}
```

Comment: I agree that `Spring.split()` is naïve, but a matcher on `=` is somehow the same approach.

Comment: Your solution is making assumption on the input format and can't be considered as a valid general solution...

Comment: Not supposed to be a general solution, there was a specific input string posted that they want to parse. I posted working code that actually parses the input string using modern idiomatic Java, downvote all you want.

Comment: Look, my solution is making an assumption on the input. True. But, so is yours. You can bring all the parsing libraries you want, they will need to make assumptions on the structure of the input too. Hence, library or Split, you will need to handle special cases. Always.

Comment: The libraries all handle the "special cases" for you. Which aren't really special cases, they are part of the CSV [specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), which if you think they are "special cases" you aren't familiar with the specification. Do you really want to re-invent, test and maintain, that birds nest of code to **correct** parse CSV formatted data.

Comment: @Yves, my regular expression for parsing the name value pairs is much more tolerant and sophisticated than splitting on `=`. It handles all the cases, numbers, quoted strings, quoted strings with embedded quotes and embedded =. How would splitting on `=` behave with more than one `=` in the input?

Comment: -1 : The [first](http://www.rubular.com/r/bVQJPIk0M4) regex fails if there is a space after the =, the [second](http://www.rubular.com/r/hAXL4iNa5N) fails if we simply add another item to the list.  Quite certainly these can be fixed by further tweeking the regex but, this just goes to prove your opening statement (+2) as to not reinvent the wheel :-).  Good answer though !

Comment: @Newtopian fixed the first one to handle all whitespace in your example. But your assertion that the second one is incorrect, is false. The second one works as designed, your example has **characters** without double quotes, it specifically looks for only **numbers** without double quotes, it isn't broken. Here is a [proper set of inputs](http://www.rubular.com/r/4QS9BWkriR) it handles as many as needed. You prove my point about using regular expressions with caution because it wasn't immediately obvious to you that it only matched numbers without double quotes. :-)

Comment: @Jarod I'M quite certain I can still find examples that break the regex and you will find ways to fix them until at one point we finally come up with an expression that gets the job done... but... this path leads to the dark side ;-P.  I'm much more in taking an existing one and improve it to make it do what you want than rolling a brand new one.  PS, the [second](http://www.rubular.com/r/pMXZkZ3UEe) one is still broken

Answer (score 0):

To separate the string by commas, the other posters are correct. It is best to use a CSV parser (your own or OTS). Considering things like commas inside quotes etc can lead to a lot of un-considered problems.

Once you have each separate token in the form:

```
key = "value"
```

I think it is easy enough to look for the first index of `'='`. Then the part before that will be the key, and the part after that will be the value. Then you can store them in a `Map<String, String>`.
This is assuming that your keys will be simple enough, and not contain = in them etc. Sometimes it's enough to take the simple route when you can restrict the problem scope.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you will want to parse the string into a map because you will be pulling various values perhaps multiple times, so it often makes sense to pay the parsing cost up-front.

If not, then here is how I would solve the problem (assuming you want to differentiate between int values and String values).:

```
public Object pullValue(String pairs, String key) {
    boolean returnString = false;
    int keyStart = pairs.indexOf(key + "=");
    if (keyStart < 0) {
        logger.error("Key " + key + " not found in key-value pairs string");
        return null;
    }
    int valueStart = keyStart + key.length() + 1;
    if (pairs.charAt(valueStart) == '"') {
        returnString = true;
        valueStart++;    // Skip past the quote mark
    }
    int valueEnd;
    if (returnString) {
        valueEnd = pairs.indexOf('"', valueStart);
        if (valueEnd < 0) {
            logger.error("Unmatched double quote mark extracting value for key " + key)
        }
        return pairs.substring(valueStart, valueEnd);
    } else {
        valueEnd = pairs.indexOf(',', valueStart);
        if (valueEnd < 0) {  // If this is the last key value pair in string
            valueEnd = pairs.length();
        }
        return Integer.decode(pairs.substring(valueStart, valueEnd));
    }

}
```

Note that this solution assumes no spaces between the key, the equals sign, and the value. If these are possible you will have to create some code to travel the string between them.

Another solution is to use a regular expression parser. You could do something like (this is untested):

```
Pattern lookingForString = Pattern.compile(key + "[ \t]*=[ \t]*[\"]([^\"]+)[\"]");
Pattern lookingForInt = Pattern.compile(key + "[ \t]*=[ \t]*([^,]+)");
Matcher stringFinder = lookingForString.matcher(pairs);
Matcher intFinder = lookingForInt.matcher(pairs);
if (stringFinder.find()) {
    return stringFinder.group(1);
} else if (intFinder.find()) {
    return Integer.decode(intFinder.group(1));
} else {
    logger.error("Could not extract value for key " + key);
    return null;
}
```

HTH

Comment: A little harsh. Unlike the other responses, at least I dealt with the question being asked and worked with the data as it was specified. It is true that I didn't recommend a generalized parser, as that is specifically NOT what was asked for. It is also true that there are some edge conditions (such as dealing with an unquoted value that was not an integer) that I didn't deal with. But as the problem was presented I think it is exactly what was asked for, and everyone else has been wasting the OPs time.

Comment: For the OP, I should point out that there are a number of assumptions I've made about your data based on the example you gave:

Comment: 1) the key value pairs string will not have unnecessary whitespace. 2) there are only 2 data types stored in the values, integers and strings. 3) all strings are double-quote delimited. 4) all integers have no quotes and are whole numbers. 5) the values never contain an equals sign character. If you can have 'value1="value2=stuff",value2="otherstuff"' then the other replies are correct, you must parse the string. If you have a guarantee that a '=' or '"' or ',' character will never appear in the value section then there is no reason to assume that parsing is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one value out of such a string, you can use String's indexOf() and substring() methods:

```
String getValue(String str, String key)
{
    int keyIndex = str.indexOf(key + "=");

    if(keyIndex == -1) return null;

    int startIndex = str.indexOf("\"", keyIndex);
    int endIndex = str.indexOf("\"", startIndex);
    String value = str.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `String.split(yourdata, ',')` and you will get a `String[]`. Then, perform `String.split(String[i],"=")`, on each entry to separate property and values.

Ideally, you should move this data in a `Properties` object instance. You can then save/load it from XML easily. It has useful methods.

**REM:** I am assuming that you are savvy enough to understand that this solution won't work if values contain the separator (i.e., the comma) in them...

Comment: Using `String.split()` is naive advice at best and bad advice at worst. What happens if the data has embedded `,` in the values? What happens if the values have embedded `"` in them?

Comment: Using the [Splitter class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) from Google Guava best fits string splitting.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson you are voting me down on assumptions you are making over the OP

Comment: @JVerstry no, `String.split(',')` is poor advice to someone asking this question, if they are asking this question, they probably don't know about the advanced backtracking you need to do to really parse CSV data correctly. It is sub optimal for parsing CSV data because it won't **correctly** parse CSV data, it only handles the most narrow naive cases, kind of like suggesting someone parse XML/XHTML with regular expression, works until it doesn't; which is most of the cases.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson With your line of thought, I can argue that you tend to shoot flies with cannon balls upon assumptions you bring to the issue. So far, there is no evidence that the cases you raise HAVE to be handled. You create the world as you see it, not as it is.

Comment: 20 years and millions of lines of code written and read, tell me the world never is as simple as it seems. "Software implementation complexity is **inversely** proportional to the complexity of the requirements". Beginners don't understand this. If you aren't handling the cases I raised, you **aren't** conforming to the CSV spec, not my call I didn't write the spec.