# Efficient way to Parse String

Tags: java, string, substring

say for example you have a string that has key values but the variables after it can change
ex:

```
KEY1=variable1, KEY2=variable2, KEY3=variable3
```

What I want to know is what is the best way to extract variable1, variable2, and variable3. It would be nice if I knew the the substrings and got them each time, but I don't bc the variables can change. Note the keys do not change

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887559/best-way-to-retrieve-a-value-from-a-string-java/5887890#5887890

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
String str = "KEY1=variable1, KEY2=variable2, KEY3=variable3";
String[] strArr = str.split(",");
String[] strArr2;
for (String string : strArr) {
    System.out.println(string);  // ---- prints key-value pair
    strArr2 = string.trim().split("=");
    System.out.println(strArr2[1]);  // ---- prints value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on Harry's solution which would handle space around the , and = in the value is.

```
String str = "KEY1=variable1, KEY2=variable2, KEY3=variable3    ,    a = b=1, c";
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (String string : str.trim().split(" *, *")) {
    String[] pair = string.split(" *= *", 2);
    map.put(pair[0], pair.length == 1 ? null : pair[1]);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

prints

```
{KEY1=variable1, KEY2=variable2, KEY3=variable3, a=b=1, c=null}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be super-efficient, no unnecessary object creation, or character by character iteration, you can use `indexOf` which is more efficient than character by character looping for large substrings.

```
public class ValueFinder {
  // For keys A, B, C will be { "A=", ", B=", ", C=" }
  private final String[] boundaries;

  /**
   * @param keyNames To parse strings like {@code "FOO=bar, BAZ=boo"}, pass in
   *     the unchanging key names here, <code>{ "FOO", "BAZ" }</code> in the
   *     example above.
   */
  public ValueFinder(String... keyNames) {
    this.boundaries = new String[keyNames.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < boundaries.length; ++i) {
      boundaries[i] = (i != 0 ? ", " : "") + keyNames[i] + "=";
    }
  }

  /**
   * Given {@code "FOO=bar, BAZ=boo"} produces <code>{ "bar", "boo" }</code>
   * assuming the ctor was passed the key names <code>{ "FOO", "BAZ" }</code>.
   * Behavior is undefined if {@code s} does not contain all the key names in
   * order.
   */ 
  public String[] parseValues(String s) {
    int n = boundaries.length;
    String[] values = new String[n];
    if (n != 0) {
      // The start of the next value through the loop.
      int pos = boundaries[0].length();
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int start = pos;
        int end;
        // The value ends at the start of the next boundary if
        // there is one, or the end of input otherwise.
        if (i + 1 != n) {
          String next = boundaries[i + 1];
          end = s.indexOf(next, pos);
          pos = end + next.length();
        } else {
          end = s.length();
        }
        values[i] = s.substring(start, end);
      }
    }
    return values;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're variable values cannot contain commas or spaces, you could simply split the string into an array using the ", " as the split token. Then you could further split each key on the equal sign to retrieve both the key and the value.